# How to set date for 2 weeks out for an automated reminder

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date, reminder

I have a SharePoint list that is populated with ticket data. There are two primary columns "Open Date" and 
"Calculated Date" I'm trying to figure out how to set the calculated date 2 weeks out from the open date and every two weeks thereafter.

Essentially, I'm using Microsoft flow to automate a process. The flow will check the ticket status if it reads open it will look at the open date and kick an email off two weeks after the open date. For example say ticket 1 is opened as of today 4/16/20, the flow will check the ticket status if it is open it will look at the open date and there will be conditions set to send an email 2 weeks after the open date. However, I will also need it to send an email every two weeks after until its closed. 4/16/20 open date >  email 4/30/20 > email 5/14/20 and so on until it's closed.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to have imported dynamic date data and a calculated date column that always reads two weeks from the imported dynamic date data. For example the imported data would be "last ticket update" ex. it's entered into SharePoint as 4/16/20 I would like another column "calculated date" to be able to change dynamically 2 weeks out from the "last ticket update." A ticket will be entered into SP with a date and status if the status remains open I need the calculated date column to be every two weeks to send a reminder. I hope that helps explain what i'm trying to do.

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting up your flow like this:

[image]

After a new item is added, initialize two variables (`ReminderDate` and `NextReminder`) that holds the initial value `addDays(triggerBody()?['Created'],14)`.

Then, add a **Control Action** of type **Do until** with a test on your status column ("Balance equal to 200" in my example). Note that this field should be from the later "Get updated item" action, not the original trigger!

Inside this, insert the **Delay until** action with the `ReminderDate` variable as the timestamp.
Insert a step to get the item (by the ID from the original trigger) so we can know if the status field is changed.

Next, add your notification email, then update the `NextReminder` variable to be `addDays(variables('ReminderDate'),14)`, finally set the variable `ReminderDate` to the value of `NextReminder`.

This loop should continue to send an email every two weeks until the ticket status is closed.

Here is my inbox with this flow running with 2 minutes instead of 2 weeks:
[image]

---

**More detailed screenshots:**

[image]
The formula used in the first variable initialization is: `addMinutes(triggerBody()?['Created'],2)`

In the second variable initialization, it is just set to the value of ReminderDate as it doesn't matter what it is yet.

[image]

In the "Do until" step, here I am using a field called "Balance". This is from the "Check the item" step, NOT from the original "When an item is created". This is important.

[image]

Final formulas: `addMinutes(variables('ReminderDate'),2)`
The last variable is set to the value of `NextReminder`.

Comment: Rune, thank you I'll give this a try. I assume this would work just as well if I set the trigger to "when a new item is created or modified." The only thing I worry about with using this method is time out. I did have a flow set up similar to this, except for some reason it was pulling all the old SharePoint data as well. For example, say I wanted an email sent to Bob Smith on 4/17/20 (as his 2 week reminder), I would also get a notification send to Sally Smith who still has an open ticket from 4/5/20 (this would send immediately instead of the 2 week time lapse).

Comment: If you do that you might end up with a LOT of reminders! Any update to the list will start a new instance of the flow - and thus a new loop with notifications...

Comment: If 1 list item equals 1 case, and the reminders should be sendt out based on when it was opened, I would use the trigger from my example. Otherwise there is something I'm not quite understanding on how you want this to work :-)

Comment: I see what you mean. Will what you described work with dynamic data? For example if the SharePoint list is not populated and say 3 tickets come in as open with dates of 4/15, 4/16, and 4/17 respectively. Will I get a reminder 2 weeks out for each of those dates? I'm trying to have the initial date come in on the ticket > reminder two weeks from the initial opening date > reminder two weeks out from the first reminder > reminder two weeks out from the second reminder and so on until it is marked closed. I hope that makes sense. I can set it to only when an item is created.

Comment: Yes, each of the three tickets will start their own flow - using the created date as the starting point for each loop.

Here's how you can test this: create the same, but use something like 5 minutes instead of 2 weeks to see it in action.

Comment: Additionally, I've added an image of what I'm trying to do. Based off of a dynamic assign date that will be imported I would like to send a reminder 2 weeks out and every 2 weeks thereafter until that entity is marked as closed. I apologize as I'm very new at using both of these MS products. I'll give it a shot and report back. Thank you Rune Sperre, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you please clarify your variable naming convention and how they could be used in the context of my flow. For example, my Assign Date column will be the day the ticket is open, the Reminder Date column will be the 2 week reminder, and the Status column will be open or closed, which will determine whether or not to run the loop. So you're saying my initialized variable should be "Reminder Date" and I assume your ['Created'] is where my Assign Date should go, Test would be my status column; however, I'm still unclear as to what goes in the delay until action?

Comment: Update: I've added images of what I have referenced thus far; however, I'm receiving the following error - "The inputs of workflow run action 'Set_variable' of type 'SetVariable' are not valid. Self reference is not supported when updating the value of variable 'ReminderDate' "

Comment: You are quite right - that did not work as expected. I have updated the answer with an improved solution. It is running here now (every 2 minutes) - will update with more screenshots after a while. As to you other date columns -- this solution only needs the Created date.

Comment: I also forgot a very important step... To fetch the item to see if it was updated. Sorry about the confusion, I updated the text in the answer as well.

Comment: Hi Rune, I updated the pictures in my original post. I'm still receiving the same error:  "The inputs of workflow run action 'Set_variable' of type 'SetVariable' are not valid. Self reference is not supported when updating the value of variable 'ReminderDate'" Can you take a look at the flow I have in the original post and see if there are any errors?

Comment: Yes, the first set variable after the email should be NextReminder, not ReminderDate.

Comment: Rune, I'm still having some difficulty getting this flow to work properly. Is there any way you would be willing to expand the screenshots of each step of your flow, similar to what I did in my original posting?

Comment: No problem, adding them now

Comment: Rune, thank you for helping me figure this issue out. Unfortunately, I'm still not getting an email for some reason. I updated the pictures in my original post. Ideally, from the SharePoint list, the only email that should be sent is for the open status, which would send 2 weeks from the assign date. I've updated the breakdown of my flow and what the flow looks like during testing. Do you have any suggestions? I've also reached out via email.